# Dict into List Comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

This is my dict and list

```
d = {1: ['val1', 'val2'], 2: ['val3', 'val4']}
l = []

for key, value in d.items():
    for sub_value in value:
        l.append(sub_value)

print (l)
```

# ['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4']

---

However, I would like to do this with **dict to list comprehension.**

I have something like this,

```
l = [sub_value for sub_value in value for key,value in d.items()]
```

Also tried,

```
l = [(sub_value for sub_value in value) for key,value in d.items()]
```

However, not quite the answer I was looking for.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that "dict into list comprehension" is not a thing. This is a list comprehension that happens to iterate over a dict -- it's no less of a list comprehension because of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will be the first to admit that list comprehension sure is confusing sometimes:

```
[sub_value for key,value in d.items() for sub_value in value]
```

This gives the required output.

Comment: Ah, just moving the orders around can work with for loops in another for loop. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You were pretty close with the first one; just the wrong order:

```
In [42]: [el for v in d.values() for el in v]
Out[42]: ['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following list comprehension:

```
l = [j for i in d for j in d[i]]
```

---

```
>>> d = {1: ['val1', 'val2'], 2: ['val3', 'val4']}
>>> l = [j for i in d for j in d[i]]
>>> l
['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4']
>>>
```